# How do I get days difference without calculate hours?

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I get days difference without counting hours accumulation? Below is my code that I've tried :

```
TimeSpan timeDifferenceLogin = (DateTime.Now).Subtract(lastTime);    
int dTimeDifferenceLogin = timeDifferenceLogin.Days;  

if (dTimeDifferenceLogin > 1)
{
    //MessageBox.Show("checkin_dayout");
    Out_Time.Text = "--:--";
    In_Time.Text = "--:--";
    btn_checkIn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    btn_checkOut.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    txtMessage.Text = "";
}
else if (dTimeDifferenceLogin < 1 && lastType == "out")
{
    //MessageBox.Show("checkout");
    DateTime lastInTime = absenList[lastData - 2].Time;
    In_Time.Text = lastInTime.ToString("HH:mm");
    Out_Time.Text = lastTime.ToString("HH:mm");
    btn_checkIn.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    btn_checkOut.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    txtMessage.Text = "See u tomorrow :D";
}
```

Example :
From Tuesday 09:23:37, I want to get the result that Wednesday 00:00:00 is a new day instead of I must wait for 24 hours which is Wednesday 09:23:37.

What should I do?

Comment: There is not only `DateTime.Now, but DateTime.Today` which returns the date at midnight, thus not considering the time.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the days from time difference, better get it directly from date

```
var lastTime = new DateTime(2014,3,25);
var daydifference =  DateTime.Now.Date - lastTime.Date;
```